# Fragments of compactness in infinitary logic with infinite quantification

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

I have been getting into infinitary logic recently, and stumbled upon $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_{1},\omega}$ and $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_{1},\omega_{1}}$. In particular I've been reading Dickman's "Large Infinitary languages" and Marker's infinitary logic book. I was particularly struck by the undefinability of well-ordering - a "fragment" of compactness - being sometimes used in place of compactness when working with $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_{1},\omega}$.

In that sense, I was wondering whether there are any known failures of expressiveness of $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_{1},\omega_{1}}$ which relate to compactness properties, or some analogous. I have a hunch that probably no such thing should exist, given how powerful the logic is, but I'd be interested to hear anything about this!

Comment: There's an analogue of Barwise compactness which holds for $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega_1}$, or indeed any reasonably-defined logic; as far as I know, however, it's not actually useful for anything (since the relevant analogue of "admissible fragment" is so nasty). See [this MO post of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/q/400575/8133).